# How to use a place holder in liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I want to use a place holder for username in GRANT command in liquibase. I use `<sql>` in liquibase xml for all my SQL commands. I am calling liquibase using SpringLiquibase. What are my options to pass a username as argument to this Liquibase instance ?

I see this page http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html has some options. But I do not want to pass it as a JVM argument or a Liquibase runner argument. Is there a possibility to pass through SpringLiquibase ?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured I could use setChangelogParameters on liquibase - http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.html

That solves my purpose.